# How to install folium for python 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, installation, python-module, folium

```
import folium as fo

map = fo.Map()
map

x = fo.FeatureGroup(name= 'My Map')

x.add_person(fo.Marker(location=[27.1750,78.0422] ,

popup='hello user' , icon=fo.Icon(color='green')))

map.add_person(x)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have the python package installed. You can install it using pip running this command in your console:

```
python -m pip install folium
```

Take a look at [Installing Python Modules](https://docs.python.org/3/installing/index.html) on the python documentation

Answer (score 0):

As explained on the docs [here](https://pypi.org/project/folium/) and [here](https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/installing.html), you can install folium by running:

```
pip install folium
```

or

```
conda install -c conda-forge folium
```